# Getting vocabulary dict for tfhub ALBERT

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

How do I get vocabulary dict/list for https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3

Answer (score 1):

The default cache location for the `tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3` model is `/tmp/tfhub_modules/602d30248ff7929470db09f7385fc895e9ceb4c0` ([more on caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching)). In the `assets` directory, you'll find `vocab.txt`, which is the used vocabulary.